# Add a comment to an array

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'd like something like this, only not ugly (I did it in paint, don't judge!)

[image: Ugly comment added by PAINT because Gimp install failed]

I'm having a very uphill battle with Tikz. Could someone give me some pointers on making something similar, preferably with Tikz? I'm open to all suggestions.

Thanks for your time!

[Edit] Added code!

```
\section*{\texorpdfstring{An Example: The Single-Fault,\\ 3-Component System}}

    To motivate the discussion, consider the single-fault, 3-component system. By construction we know the state variable for the original system with no swapped components is $0,0,0$, and we are given that the output is 0. Let's consider the case where the third component, $C_3$, is faulty. The truth table with the encoding above and the givens is:


\[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}
C_1&C_2&C_3 & Result \\           \hline
0&0&0&\mathbf{0}\tikzmark{byconstruction} \\  \hline
0&0&1&\mathbf{1}\\ \hline
0&1&0&\mathbf{0}\\ \hline
0&1&1&\mathbf{1}\\ \hline
1&0&0&\mathbf{0}\\ \hline
1&0&1&\mathbf{1}\\ \hline
1&1&0&\mathbf{0}\\ \hline
1&1&1&\mathbf{1}
\end{array} \]
```

Comment: In the very least, it would really be courteous to supply the community with some code they can use as a starting point... Where should the "By construction" point to? The first row? The column with heading `f`?

Comment: Sorry about that! Fixed above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library: you place a mark in a designated element and use the mark to draw/place elements (the code needs two or three runs for the arrows and labels to reach their final position):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{*{5}{c}|c}
a & b & c & d & e & f\tikzmark{starta} \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\tikzmark{startb}
\end{array}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[<-]
  ([shift={(4pt,2pt)}]pic cs:starta) -- ++(1cm,0pt) node[anchor=west] {By construction};
\draw[<-,red]
  ([shift={(4pt,4pt)}]pic cs:startb) -- ++(1cm,0pt) node[anchor=west,ellipse,fill=red!30] {By same reason};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]